# problem invoking windows' netsh in cygwin's bash shell

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have 3 computers (let me call them N1, N2, N3) with the following systems:

- **N1**:  Windows 2019 Server Essential 64 bit, with CYGWIN_NT-10.0 -3.0.7(0.338/5/3) x86_64
- **N2**:  Windows 10 professional 64 bit, with CYGWIN_NT-10.0 - 3.1.7(0.340/5/3) x86_64
- **N3**:  Windows 10 professional 64 bit, with CYGWIN_NT-10.0 - 3.1.7(0.340/5/3) x86_64

Accessing them through Cygwin's SSHD from a Linux machine, I can (remotely) run on all of these 3 computers (windows-)commands like

- `/c/Windows/System32/NET  start  <SERVICENAME>`
- `/c/Windows/System32/ATTRIB`
- `/c/Windows/System32/HELP`
- `/c/Windows/System32/NETSH`
- ...

and they all work as expected.

Except the command `NETSH` on **N3**!

On N3, invoking

```
/c/Windows/System32/NETSH
```

does nothing at all: no error message, no command prompt, even when providing arguments like "?" (with or without quotes) or any other args, when using fully qualified command-path or command-NAME only, just nothing happens, which looks like this:

```
  user@machine ~ # /c/Windows/System32/NETSH
  user@machine ~ #
```

(NB: on the problem machine, N3, also with a Cygwin version a little bit older than the newest (actual) one, CYGWIN_NT-10.0 - 3.1.4(0.340/5/3) x86_64, the results were the same)

Is there anyone having an idea??
Thank you!!

Schogol

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the interaction between the `Mintty` and the need of `netsh` to be interactive and been not a Cygwin program. See for details:

https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#inputoutput-interaction-with-alien-programs

If you run `netsh` under `Cygwin` using the `Cygwin.bat` present on you root, you have no issue as the terminal is the same of `CMD`

```
$ netsh
netsh>interface
In zukünftigen Versionen von Windows wird die Netsh-Funktionalität
für TCP/IP von Microsoft entfernt.
..
Unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=217627 finden Sie
weitere Informationen zu PowerShell-Befehlen für TCP/IP.
netsh interface>
netsh interface>quit
```

A workaround under `Mintty` is to use `winpty` as intermediate
https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/releases

Assuming you are using a 64bit system:

```
$ wget https://github.com/rprichard/winpty/releases/download/0.4.3/winpty-0.4.3-cygwin-2.8.0-x64.tar.gz
$ tar -xf winpty-0.4.3-cygwin-2.8.0-x64.tar.gz
$ cp -r  winpty-0.4.3-cygwin-2.8.0-x64/* /usr/local
$ winpty netsh
netsh>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, but: 1) All those interactions I do through ssh from remote, using a Linux system, so mintty is not involved. 2) On 2 machines it works, and on the third it doesn't, so this seems not to be a systematic problem

Comment: 3) if I start cmd within my bash shell, going into windows commandline, netsh works as expected, so it is obviously present and not (yet) removed by microsoft.

Comment: `3`?  I never wrote that `netsh` was removed. It is its output that is delayed / buffered / diverted by one of the terminal layers

Comment: 3 refered to this: "In zukünftigen Versionen von Windows wird die Netsh-Funktionalität für TCP/IP von Microsoft entfernt." Seems I missunderstood it, sorry.  But is there a way to work around the delaying / buffering / diverting in a shell running in Linux ssh-connected to Win10?

Comment: have you tried `winpty` anyway ? I have no Linux box anymore so I can only do Cygwin to Cygwin ssh test. By the way I can not also reproduce anymore the issue on my machine, so `netsh` runs without output issue. I am sure to have not installed anything from Cygwin that could alter the status, very puzzling !

Comment: No, I didn't, because neither mintty nor winpty would ever be involved in my connection from Linux to Windows-Cygwin. But I found a workaround which works well for me. I will post it here. Thank you anyway for your efforts, I really appreciate very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick-and-dirty type of workaround for my problem, but it works very well for me. (My goal actually was to create a shell script to check /var/log/sshd.log and look for brute force attacks, which just exploded last few months. Then this script should create Windows firewall rules to block these IP numbers for a certain time. This is what I needed the access to 'netsh' for.)

My workaround for the above problem:

I created another shell script

```
/usr/local/bin/netsh
```

with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash 
exec  /c/Windows/System32/CMD  /c  "C:\Windows\System32\NETSH $@"
```

Of course this needs a PATH variable which has

```
/usr/local/bin
```

as first element.

This way I (and my script) can use the 'netsh' tool transparently.